# Quorum - Was the raft log corrupted, truncated, or lost? Incremental/Differential Backup Strategy and Restoring EVM State in a Quorum Node

Tags: quorum, backup, raft

Say, there is only one quorum node within each organisation (among many other quorum nodes which are spread out in other organisations) and that quorum node encountered some catastrophic incident where all the data (i.e., EVM state) is wiped out.

How can one restore the data? Or perhaps the question is how can one backup the evm state? What will be the backup and recovery strategy?

Does connecting the quorum node back to the network work? I tried removing the entire node data and tried to connect the quorum node back it did not work. I am using Raft consensus and the error returned: Was the raft log corrupted, truncated, or lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Quorum, all the nodes are synced up same way as regular Ethereum would, except the blocks may come in from a leader rather than another node. So, a new node joining the blockchain would sync up as usual by receiving blocks from the current leader + participants. Once it catches up, it will be receiving blocks from the leader.

Geth / Quorum allow for a pretty simple backup strategy: ensure the /data directory is properly and periodically backed up and thats all you need to recover and restart the failed node. Things get a lot more complex with Constellation side of the things:

- loosing your private/public keys means there is no recovering of the private state
- after recovery and rejoining, you would need to ask participants of the chain to execute resend command on their own Constellations to receive private payloads for whatever your node happens to have missed

Comment: Thanks again. Am trying to deploy what I have built in production. Are there public key infrastructure system (pki) and/or hardware security module (hsm) that quorum can work with that i can leverage on? Private public key management is crucial for success. Many many thanks

Comment: No, not at the moment, meaning that you'd need to implement the bridges yourself.